# What is the difference between this 2 margins?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a homework for university is to make a website.
So i have a div id named container that is my div that will define the width for all my page.
So my question is the teacher said to put

```
#container {
    width:Anyvaluepx;
     margin:auto;

}
```

So i was looking for ways to center a container and i saw people saying to put  something like that:

```
#container {
  width:valuepx;
   margin 0 auto;

}
```

I think is not necessary my html file but i will post too:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Eagle's Guitar Shop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
 </div>






</div> <!--Finish Container div-->
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is simple what is the difference between use margin:auto; and margin: 0 auto;?

Thanks for all the question so the margin works for re-size the website with the screen resolution right? so it is better to let all auto? or 0 auto;?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Both will put your div horizontally in center. Adding 0 ensure top and bottom margins will be zero. It doesn't have to do anything with aligning center. For more infi reffer to the following post.

[What does auto do in margin:0 auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170772/what-does-auto-do-in-margin0-auto)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `margin: auto;` sets all margins to `auto`; whereas `margin: 0 auto` sets the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` both to `0` and `margin-left` and `margin-right` both to `auto`.

```
margin: auto;
```

is equivalent to:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

Whereas

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

is equivalent to:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
```

Similarly,

```
margin: 0 auto 10px;
```

would be equivalent to:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
```

References:

- [CSS Properties: `margin`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin).

Comment: hm so my teacher is wrong?  So the correct way is use always margin:0 auto;? Thank you.

Comment: No, top and bottom margins **can** be `auto`, they will simply deafult to zero for a box which is not absolutely positioned.

Comment: @Carlo: agreed, just deleted that assertion (after a moment's thought).

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto` is the proper way to **center** a container. The difference is `margin: auto` messes with vertical and horizontal axis where as the latter focuses on the horizontal.