# CSS - Overriding CSS Reset

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet

Problem: `margin: 0 auto` does not work on body. `background-color: #EEEEEE` on the other hand, is working even though they are on the same block.

index.php:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>MForte</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bodyStyleSheet.css">
    </head>

    <body id="container">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

reset.css:

```
/**
* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
* http://cssreset.com
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

bodyStyleSheet.css:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

What I have tried:

1) Swapping `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">` and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bodyStyleSheet.css">` to each other.

2) Removed the `id` of the `body` from the `index.php` file and replaced the `#container` by `body`

3) To test the scenario, since `border: 0` is declared on `reset.css`, I tried to create a `table` on `index.php` containing 2 rows. `border: 1` is declared on `reset.css` in the `table` tag. Border didn't show.

Comment: You've done nothing to stop `body` from simply taking up the entire width allowable, so that's why `margin: 0 auto;` won't do anything. First fix the width of `body` so that it is not as wide as `html`, and you will see the `margin` doing something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170772/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, you are trying to horizontally center `body` element which has a default `width` of `100%` so even if you want to horizontally center the `body` you cannot, as it is `100%` in `width` and actually designers never `center` the `body` tag.. so if you want, nest a container `div` inside the `body` element, assign some fixed `width` and than use `margin: 0 auto;`. So alter your DOM like

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
   </div>
</body>

#container {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also, if you are looking to apply `background` to entire viewport than leave the `background` property on the `body` element, if you want the `background` only for the horizontally centered element than move the `background` property in `#container`

---

Also, CSS reset has nothing to do with this, CSS Reset is used to reset the default styles applied by browser stylesheet, some prefer to use universal `*` selector to reset `margin` and `padding` and some do reset the `outline` as well like

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
```

But some prefer CSS Reset Stylesheets which minimizes cross browser differences to minimal.. So you can opt for any option.

---

Last but not the least, you are talking about the overriding, using Reset stylesheet, those stylesheet always uses minimal specificity selectors, using `class` or `id` will make your selectors anyways specific than the selectors used in the Reset Stylesheet, so don't use `!important` unless required unless you will end up in a mess, better use *specific selectors*.

Comment: Hi Mr. Alien, thanks for a fast response. Setting a fixed width to the body resolved my problem. Also, thank you for pointing some other important factors. One last question, I also tried to create a table settings the border size on table {} at reset.css but didn't show upon rendering. What could possible go wrong with that?

Comment: @MichaelArdan Edited my answer, and don't use fixed `width` on `body`, consider using a container element instead

Answer (score 0):

Use !important in css/bodyStyleSheet.css

such as

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #EEEEEE !important;
}
```

Good article on Smashing Magazine here

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: Why use `!important`?

Comment: I'm very sorry for not including the use if !important in the question even though I was able to try it. But thank you for your time. + for this. This could be useful to other viewers.

Comment: !important overrides the previous css declarationof a dom object and also elevates the scope strength. If I remember correctly (someone correct me about this), if used in a css file it can override inline css as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, Agreed with you :)

Comment: This approach is not sustainable. You'd have a whole lot of `!important` until the point where it's hard to track what's going on