# Center text within a div

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty trying to center my navigation text on my page. I want all my links to be in the center of my page the whole time, even if I re-size my window.
Thanks for your time.

HTML:

```
<div id="navcont">
     <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
            <li class="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="#talktome">Talk to me</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navcont{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#navigation{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "TYPOGRAPH PRO" arial;
}
#navigation ul li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    width:120px;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover{
    color:#217c7e;
}
```

Comment: I like helping people. But this has been asked about a billion times. It would only take a few minutes to search and to find the answer literally -> In the related i see 10 sorry for being an ahole but just being honest.

Comment: Horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: `text-align:center` is your friend.

Comment: I've already tried this, but the nav is not 100% centered, its offset to the right slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
text-align:center;
```

for this example. But if you make it more complex you may want to look at [*margin:0 auto;*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170772/what-does-auto-do-in-margin0-auto) on the parent div. Also worth noting that in order for it to actually look center you will need to adjust the margins automatically applied to UL and LI

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4eF3/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add `text-align: center` to your `ul`.

```
#navigation ul{
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will center all the `li` elements, as well as the text inside them. If you don't want the text to center you could add a `text-align: left` to the `li` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/ctCKg/

**EDIT:** But like others have said, this should be an easy search or trial and error for you. Lots of ways to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Add one property to your div CSS my friend

```
 #navigation {
   font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "TYPOGRAPH PRO" arial;
   text-align:center;
 }
```

like this

Comment: @user3179106 , is it helps you

Comment: @user3179106 if it helps you please right click on my answer so it will be helpfull for others my friend