# Div not centered when using display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have been using `display: table` for my `html` along with `display: table-cell` for my `body` lately, to make all of the contents of my page appear at the very center of the screen. While, this works with paragraphs, headings, inputs and labels etc.(as far as I have tested at least), it doesn't seem to work with `div` elements. 

Is there any way to make this work for `div` elements like it does for the other ones?  Pure CSS solution would be best.

**Example** ([also on Codepen](http://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/pbBkbk))

```css
html {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.leaf {
  border-radius: 15px 2px 15px 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leaf">Why am I not centered?</div>
<p>And why am I centered?</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `margin: 0 auto;`.. Working right.

```css
html {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.leaf {
  border-radius: 15px 2px 15px 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="leaf">Why am I not centered?</div>
<p>And why am I centered?</p>
```

Comment: It does, why does it do so however? How does the `margin: 0 auto` rule make it do that?

Comment: When you have specified a width on the object that you have applied `margin: 0 auto` to, the object will sit centrally within it's parent container.

Specifying `auto` as the second parameter basically tells the browser to automatically determine the left and right margins itself, which it does by setting them equally. It guarantees that the left and right margins will be set to the same size. The first parameter 0 indicates that the top and bottom margins will both be set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just add *margin: 0 auto;* to .leaf class.

```css
html {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.leaf {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 15px 2px 15px 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leaf">Why am I not centered?</div>
<p>And why am I centered?</p>
```

Comment: @Angelos, for further info about the auto trick, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170772/what-does-auto-do-in-margin0-auto)