# How to make this iframe code responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe

Hi I want to make fix this iframe into the center between the left table and right table. I'm having trouble with making my site responsive and it appears different on different resolutions: (http://footkick.16mb.com/)

As I said, I wanted this to be bang in the center of the left and right table regardless of resolution. If you can help me out: THANKS SO MUCH

[<]iframe class="channels" src="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/fixtures" scrolling="yes" style="height: 990px; width: 619px;margin: 45px 0px 0px 115px; border:2px solid black; outline-style: solid; outline-color: green; ">

css:

```
height: 990px;
width: 619px;
margin: 45px 0px 0px 115px;
border: 2px solid black;
outline-style: solid;
outline-color: green;
```

Comment: Well done with your site!

Comment: Cheers, Jethro Hazelhurst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
margin: 45px auto 0px;
display: block
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Iframe element remove: `margin: 45px 0px 0px 115px;` and add `margin: 0 auto; display:block;`.

[Display block:](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

[Margin: 0 auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170772/what-does-auto-do-in-margin0-auto)

Also please learn about why inline css is a bad practice

Comment: Mad help, cheers for that. Yeah I still have a lot learn about CSS// HTML

Answer (score 0):

turn the iframe to a block element like so

```
  .your-frame {
 display: block;
width: 80%;
margin: 2% auto;
}
```