# is there a way to center align this span element without affecting how the element renders?

Tags: html, css

I'm rendering rating stars using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css) and I need to center all the elements of my html page, including the stars. The page will look like this:

[image]

Problem is, when I use `<center>` or `<style="text-align: center;">` the stars end up looking like this:

code:

```
<center>
  <span class="stars">4</span>
</center>
```

result:

[image: 4/5 star rating]

Is there a way to center the span class without affecting how it renders? I tried using margin-left/right but they look pretty bad when I change the size of the browser/use it on a phone.

What it is:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: you want it to center in the div?

Comment: yeah, added pics to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `margin: 0 auto;`. It will center to its parent div..

If you want to understand more about `margin: 0 auto;` try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170772/what-does-auto-do-in-margin0-auto).

Comment: should I be using this as such: <span class="stars" style="margin: 0 auto;">4</span>? I'm using bootstrap so my parent div is <div class="col-md-12">, I tried placing the margin in the css as well, both does not work.

Comment: is there a reason for you to use span? if not try changing span to div..

Comment: if you want to use span add `display:table;` && `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: I think the span class was necessary for the stars to render. `display:table;` && `margin:0 auto;` worked! thanks.

Comment: @Chris I'm glad i was able to help.. happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without more information about context and what you're trying to do, but have you tried using CSS rather than HTML tags?

.stars {
text-align: center
}

Comment: just tried this, similar results to using html tags